# Changing properties of different types of materials at the same time?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, blueprint, unreal

Silly example, but in geometry dash there is a grouping system that allows multiple objects to be effected by the same trigger, no matter the type. Is there any way to do this with unreal objects? For example scaling?

The real problem is that I need to select which mesh/material needs to be changed, but while selecting multiple objects they may differ.

Here is the video of how geometry dash works:

https://youtu.be/mCapH4nfhzY

For example, I tried setting material from level BP, but the BP requires an object reference, ex "cube > get material". However in the level BP it does not allow for that. Is there a way I can get get a reference to objects of that material? (P.S, I know that you can just change the properties of the material by itself, but I specifically want to change all objects with a certain "group id", like scaling all objects by (2,2,2) if it has this ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends on where you want to do that (in editor *or* game).

My understanding is that you want to do that in-editor.

1. You can edit how editor works by making a class:

[image: Class image]

And coding in construction tab:

[image: Construction tab]

There you can use your mouse to detect what object is clicked by a node get hit result under cursor by channel (search it).